# Change comma color of a number in javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, number-formatting

Did you have any trick to change the color of comma in a number like :

```
1,850,358
```

**withtout** addind any css class, styles, or html separators as :

```
1<span class="red">,</span>850<span class="red">,</span>358
```

I am quite out of ideas..

Comment: Inline styling is what you're looking for.

Comment: Do you actually mean no span tags? Because no, that's not possible without markup of some kind.

Comment: I mean no html or any value separator

Answer (score 0):

Use style?

```
1<span style="color:red">,</span>850<span style="color:pink">,</span>358
```

The better way is probably to define an [AngularJS directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) or [Polymer web component](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/) that turns all specified characters into a color. The markup could look like something like this:

```
<character-magic char="," color="#fa1122">You will notice in this text, that every comma has a specific color. Isn't this great, no?</character-magic>
```

In the end, the component/directive will still do the inline styling as mentioned above with style.